# Android build failing on AppCenter but building fine on Android studio

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, visual-studio-app-center

When I run my Android build from my Android studio it builds absolutely file.

When I run the same source which is checked into github from AppCenter it fails with the following error on Gradle.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this would be happening?

> ============================================================================== Task         : Gradle Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper
>   script Version      : 1.128.0 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   Help         : [More
>   Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613720)
>   ============================================================================== SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
>   [command]/Users/vsts/agent/2.148.1/work/1/s/android/gradlew
>   -DMOBILECENTER_BUILD_VERSION=17 -DAPPCENTER_BUILD_VERSION=17 -p android clean :app:assembleDevKernelDebug Starting a Gradle Daemon
>   (subsequent builds will be faster) Gradle 4.4 Parallel execution with
>   configuration on demand is an incubating feature. Download
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/2.0.0/gradle-download-task-2.0.0.pom
>   Download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.pom
>   Resolved com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 in :classpath  Resolved
>   com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1 in :classpath  Resolved
>   de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:2.0.0 in :classpath  Download
>   https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/undercouch/gradle-download-task/2.0.0/gradle-download-task-2.0.0.jar
>   Download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
>   Project android at : is either no Android app project or build version
>   has not been set to override. Skipping... Resolved
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 in
>   :@react-native-community_netinfo:classpath  Project
>   @react-native-community_netinfo at :@react-native-community_netinfo is
>   either no Android app project or build version has not been set to
>   override. Skipping... Download
>   https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
>   Download
>   https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.28.1/gradle-1.28.1.pom
>   Resolved io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1 in :app:classpath  Download
>   https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.28.1/gradle-1.28.1.jar
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in
>   [src/prod/min/sdk/dev/kernel/debug, src/prod/min/sdk/dev/debug,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/dev/kernel, src/prod/min/sdk/dev/kernelDebug,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/debug, src/prod/min/sdk/dev,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/devDebug, src/prod/min/debug, src/prod/min/sdk,
>   src/prod/min/sdkDebug, src/prodMinSdkDevKernel/debug,
>   src/debug/prodMinSdkDevKernel, src/prod/debug, src/prod/min,
>   src/prod/minDebug, src/prodMinSdkDevKernel, src/debug,
>   src/prodMinSdkDevKernelDebug, src/prod, src/prodDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Could not find
>   google-services.json while looking in
>   [src/prod/min/sdk/dev/kernel/release, src/prod/min/sdk/dev/release,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/dev/kernel, src/prod/min/sdk/dev/kernelRelease,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/release, src/prod/min/sdk/dev,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/devRelease, src/prod/min/release, src/prod/min/sdk,
>   src/prod/min/sdkRelease, src/prodMinSdkDevKernel/release,
>   src/release/prodMinSdkDevKernel, src/prod/release, src/prod/min,
>   src/prod/minRelease, src/prodMinSdkDevKernel, src/release,
>   src/prodMinSdkDevKernelRelease, src/prod, src/prodRelease]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Could not find
>   google-services.json while looking in
>   [src/prod/min/sdk/prod/kernel/debug, src/prod/min/sdk/prod/debug,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/prod/kernel, src/prod/min/sdk/prod/kernelDebug,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/debug, src/prod/min/sdk/prod,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/prodDebug, src/prod/min/debug, src/prod/min/sdk,
>   src/prod/min/sdkDebug, src/prodMinSdkProdKernel/debug,
>   src/debug/prodMinSdkProdKernel, src/prod/debug, src/prod/min,
>   src/prod/minDebug, src/prodMinSdkProdKernel, src/debug,
>   src/prodMinSdkProdKernelDebug, src/prod, src/prodDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Could not find
>   google-services.json while looking in
>   [src/prod/min/sdk/prod/kernel/release, src/prod/min/sdk/prod/release,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/prod/kernel, src/prod/min/sdk/prod/kernelRelease,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/release, src/prod/min/sdk/prod,
>   src/prod/min/sdk/prodRelease, src/prod/min/release, src/prod/min/sdk,
>   src/prod/min/sdkRelease, src/prodMinSdkProdKernel/release,
>   src/release/prodMinSdkProdKernel, src/prod/release, src/prod/min,
>   src/prod/minRelease, src/prodMinSdkProdKernel, src/release,
>   src/prodMinSdkProdKernelRelease, src/prod, src/prodRelease]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Could not find
>   google-services.json while looking in
>   [src/dev/min/sdk/dev/kernel/debug, src/dev/min/sdk/dev/debug,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/dev/kernel, src/dev/min/sdk/dev/kernelDebug,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/debug, src/dev/min/sdk/dev, src/dev/min/sdk/devDebug,
>   src/dev/min/debug, src/dev/min/sdk, src/dev/min/sdkDebug,
>   src/devMinSdkDevKernel/debug, src/debug/devMinSdkDevKernel,
>   src/dev/debug, src/dev/min, src/dev/minDebug, src/devMinSdkDevKernel,
>   src/debug, src/devMinSdkDevKernelDebug, src/dev, src/devDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Could not find
>   google-services.json while looking in
>   [src/dev/min/sdk/dev/kernel/release, src/dev/min/sdk/dev/release,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/dev/kernel, src/dev/min/sdk/dev/kernelRelease,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/release, src/dev/min/sdk/dev,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/devRelease, src/dev/min/release, src/dev/min/sdk,
>   src/dev/min/sdkRelease, src/devMinSdkDevKernel/release,
>   src/release/devMinSdkDevKernel, src/dev/release, src/dev/min,
>   src/dev/minRelease, src/devMinSdkDevKernel, src/release,
>   src/devMinSdkDevKernelRelease, src/dev, src/devRelease]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Could not find
>   google-services.json while looking in
>   [src/dev/min/sdk/prod/kernel/debug, src/dev/min/sdk/prod/debug,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/prod/kernel, src/dev/min/sdk/prod/kernelDebug,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/debug, src/dev/min/sdk/prod,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/prodDebug, src/dev/min/debug, src/dev/min/sdk,
>   src/dev/min/sdkDebug, src/devMinSdkProdKernel/debug,
>   src/debug/devMinSdkProdKernel, src/dev/debug, src/dev/min,
>   src/dev/minDebug, src/devMinSdkProdKernel, src/debug,
>   src/devMinSdkProdKernelDebug, src/dev, src/devDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Could not find
>   google-services.json while looking in
>   [src/dev/min/sdk/prod/kernel/release, src/dev/min/sdk/prod/release,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/prod/kernel, src/dev/min/sdk/prod/kernelRelease,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/release, src/dev/min/sdk/prod,
>   src/dev/min/sdk/prodRelease, src/dev/min/release, src/dev/min/sdk,
>   src/dev/min/sdkRelease, src/devMinSdkProdKernel/release,
>   src/release/devMinSdkProdKernel, src/dev/release, src/dev/min,
>   src/dev/minRelease, src/devMinSdkProdKernel, src/release,
>   src/devMinSdkProdKernelRelease, src/dev, src/devRelease]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use
>   registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) Project appcenter at
>   :appcenter is either no Android app project or build version has not
>   been set to override. Skipping... Project appcenter-analytics at
>   :appcenter-analytics is either no Android app project or build version
>   has not been set to override. Skipping... Project appcenter-crashes at
>   :appcenter-crashes is either no Android app project or build version
>   has not been set to override. Skipping... Resolved
>   com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 in
>   :react-native-vector-icons:classpath  Project
>   react-native-vector-icons at :react-native-vector-icons is either no
>   Android app project or build version has not been set to override.
>   Skipping... WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version
>   (26.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version
>   (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4. Android SDK Build Tools
>   27.0.3 will be used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each
>   version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the
>   build tools.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'assembleDevKernelDebug' not found in project ':app'.
> - Try: Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 42s Error:
>   /Users/vsts/agent/2.148.1/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return
>   code: 1
>       at ChildProcess. (/Users/vsts/agent/2.148.1/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/1.128.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/toolrunner.js:569:30)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
>       at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)
>
> ### [error]Error: /Users/vsts/agent/2.148.1/work/1/s/android/gradlew failed with return code: 1

Answer (score 0):

You probably have invalid build variants. Go to your `build.gradle`, it should look like this.

```
  flavorDimensions 'remoteKernel'
  productFlavors {
    devKernel {
      dimension 'remoteKernel'
    }
    prodKernel {
      dimension 'remoteKernel'
    }
  }
```

This will change again in the next version of expo.

Comment: What if you're not using expo?

Answer (score -2):

I started having the same error as Robert Hanaway this morning. If I run my pipelines on a macos agent if fails with the 502 error response. However, if I run it with a hostedvs2017 agent it works fine.

Comment: This is not really the same as my problem, there are no 502 errors being throw on my issue